# Strange force close

Tags: android, eclipse, audio

I have one main activity and an xml file with 3 different buttons (three different gun sounds)

So, when the user clicks one of the buttons a gunsound will be played.

here's how it looks -

```
public class gunstats extends Activity {

    public gunstats(Bundle onSavedStateInstance) {


        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.deagle);

        Button button3 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the problem is that when I open the app in an emulator, it all force closes.
When I check the logcat, it says "Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.gunstats.gunstats"

What is causing this?

Comment: You should really go through some of the basic tutorials on the android dev website

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are executing code in the constructor. You should not execute any code in an `Activity`'s constructor. You should move all that code into `Activity#onCreate`.

You should become extremely familiar with the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).

Comment: Im still getting force close;


public class gunstats extends Activity {
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.deagle);

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete class? If so:

1. An Activity has no constructor (at least non you should ever touch)
2. You need to implement the `onCreate()` method
3. You have nowhere set a content with `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that part!
Thanks, for helping me out guys!

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that you are not following the `Activity` lifecycle.
Is `R.drawable.deagle` your sound file?  If so, it shouldn't be in the `/drawable/` directory.  Move it to somewhere like `/raw/`.

Here are a couple of examples: [Audio and Video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html), [Audio Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/59.html)

Here are the docs for [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)